# Cannot update in macOS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, safari, software-update

I downgraded `High Sierra` to `Sierra` recently (clean install, erased disk, didn't restore anything from Time Machine after installation), and now when I want to update Safari or install Security Update 2017-001, I'm getting "Cannot Verify ...." error.

For example when updating Safari to 11.0.1 I get this message:

```
An error has occurred
“Safari” could not be verified.(311)
```

Comment: Remember stumbling onto the issue, it's probably the side effect of a faulty (faulty, as in, Apple screwed it, my opinion) purchase protection system - don't remember the solution but definitely share your pain and it's concerning for me too, as I also seek to downgrade to Sierra :(

Comment: @KaanSoral After 2-3 days and many tries (logging out and in to App store etc) finally today I was able to update everything. I'm not sure, but maybe it was because I bought and downloaded some apps from the app store.